# How to configure Nginx not to cache error returned

Tags: json, caching, nginx

We have a nginx to cache the json return (such as {"returnVal":10}) of an API call. We have to set the refresh interval as 1 hour due to some business consideration. We run into the case that sometimes the api call return json response  {"returnVal":null} due to some intermittent error and nginx cached this "null" and serve to all the API calls before the next refresh comes. Can I configure nginx to do not cache the return when it is an error/null value?

Comment: Normally nginx doesn't care what is inside of response body. It would be much easier if your backed would return some additional http header for such responses.

Comment: As has already been said, the only right way to deal with this problem would be to modify your API so that it would return the [X-Accel-Expires](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cache_valid) header set to 0 in case of an error. However, if for some reason you cannot modify the API, Nginx still might provide a couple of effective (even if inadvisable) tricks that could help. But it would be very difficult to suggest something specific without looking at your configuration first.

Comment: Unfortunately, we cannot change the API, as it is owned by 3rd party. We want to cache the response is due to business consideration that they charge by no. of calls and we donnot really need to have real time update. Could u share a few of those tricks?

Answer (score 0):

HTTP error code (4xx, 5xx) is the best option to setup and control caching, so you can do something like that:

```
 proxy_cache_valid      200 1m;
 proxy_cache_valid      403 1h;
```

In case of problems with setting specific header up you can set cache key as a body (works only if error response body is the same but none errors are always different):

```
proxy_cache_key "$request_uri|$request_body";
```